# Creating a DLL in GCC or Cygwin?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, compiler-construction, c99

I need help to compile a script ("iterator.c") into a DLL. I can't use VS2010 since it does **not** support the features added to C in the C99 standard (I'm using "complex.h" but VB doesn't support it).

I've been looking for a substitute but all I've found is GCC which I don't know how to install/use (really, I've spent like half an hour reading through the documentation and I don't even understand how am I supposed to install it), and Cygwin, which I've already installed but I don't know how to use either. Also, I've installed MinGW but I think it's the same as Cygwin more or less, and I still don't know how to make a DLL.

It's not like I've been all lazy and haven't even tried it, it's just that these compilers aren't like nothing I've ever used before (mostly Python IDLE and Visual Studio, which make things pretty easy for you). I'm kind of lost.

Could someone give me some advice on how to use this tools to make a DLL that I can access from another script? It is really important.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must place __declspec(dllexport) in front of the method you wish to export such as, you could #define this to max it easier

```
EXPORT_DLL void hello() { ... }
```

To compile the dll use

```
gcc -c -mno-cygwin mydll.c
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libmylib.dll.a
```

then to attach

```
gcc -o myexe.exe test.o mydll.dll
```

EDIT: Forgot the most important piece, you need to make a mydll.h file to include your method definition so the compiler knows to reserve a spot for the linker to fill in later on. It's as simple as

```
#ifndef MYDLL_H
#define MYDLL_H

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#define EXPORT_DLL __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT_DLL void hello();

#endif
```

Comment: Isn't that `__declspec` not `__delspec`?

Comment: extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: Thanks guys for catching that, typos when writing on the fly.

Comment: extern "C" allows other non-c programs to use this dll properly

Comment: so that input (gcc -c mydll.c
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o -Wl,--out-implib) should give me a DLL of my code. Now I just have to figure out how to install GCC. Thanks to the people who answered :D By the way, where does exactly does that input go? The system console? A console I'll have when I install GCC?...

Comment: to install gcc run the Cygwin installer and find it under the development list and put a check next to it to install it

Comment: it goes into the input in the Cygwin console

Comment: If you try this on cygwin's gcc you will end up with your DLL linked with cygwin1.dll, which is murder if the EXE is not. use -m-no-cygwin (or is it -mno-cygwin) as an option to gcc to avoid this.

Comment: @Joshua, good point this way the exe will run in both mingw and cygwin environments correctly.

Comment: `-mno-cygwin` is correct, and both the Cygwin and MinGW linkers support this option, even though it is redundant for a standalone MinGW installation since MinGW is the default target rather than Cygwin.

Comment: Sorry but is it `-Wl --out-implib` not `-Wl,--out-implib`? It gives me an error otherwise :/

Comment: @Daniel sorry forgot the last argument to that, let me edit it