# Call c function from python wouldn't work

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am almost sure that I did this once a year ago... Not it just wouldn't work. Weird. I must be making a minor mistake somewhere... Please help!

I have the following toy c code:

```
// testdll.c
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

And then, since I am using Windows 7, I used WinSDK 7.1's x64 C/C++ compiler to compile it:

```
cl testdll.c /TC /LD
```

The output is testdll.dll.

Then, in my Python 3.3, I used:

```
In [12]: import ctypes

In [13]: lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./testdll.dll')

In [14]: lib
Out[14]: <CDLL './testdll.dll', handle f7000000 at a43ea58>

In [15]: lib.sum
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-309017dbbec8>", line 1, in <module>
    lib.sum

  File "C:\WinPython2\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)

  File "C:\WinPython2\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))

AttributeError: function 'sum' not found
```

It can't find this function! It's driving me crazy. Since I used pure C, and I used /TC during compiling, it shouldn't be a name mangling issue.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you all so much!

**EDIT 2014/02/13**
I tried to compile it with gcc also, but with no luck. Same old problem happens.
I used dir() in python, and realized everything should be in it - just not the correct name, by which I mean it can't be called via fun.sum. It is able to recognize that the result type of the function is an int.

```
In [34]: dir(lib)
Out[34]: 
['_FuncPtr',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_func_flags_',
 '_func_restype_',
 '_handle',
 '_name']

In [35]: lib._func_restype_
Out[35]: ctypes.c_long
```

Comment: @eryksun It worked! Thank you so much. That saved me days! 1) I don't think this problem can be easily googled (compared to how often it happens), and then I realized this is because it is windows-specific; linux'd be fine. 2) From the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721364/creating-a-dll-in-gcc-or-cygwin I guess gcc needs to do the same thing, but I can't find a good document link from cygwin/gcc to elaborate about this. Can't believe that this page http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html don't even mention it! 3) And finally, could you please make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @eryksun Or if you'd prefer saving some time, I don't mind organizing and posting it as a solution at all. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to export a symbol is via an option to the linker:

```
cl testdll.c /LD /link /export:sum
```

This doesn't scale. A better option is to use the `__declspec(dllexport)` modifier in the declaration. Refer to [Exporting from a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the Visual studio docs.

Apply it conditionally as follows:

```c
#ifdef BUILD_TESTDLL
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

/* declaration */
TESTAPI int sum(int a, int b);

/* definition */
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

When linking via the import lib, declarations should use `__declspec(dllimport)`, which is the default for `TESTAPI`. When building the DLL, define `BUILD_TESTDLL` in the project settings or on the command-line via `/D`.

Finally, for the ultimate in flexibility, use a .def file such as the following:

```
LIBRARY TESTDLL
EXPORTS
    sum @ 10 NONAME 
    sum_alias=sum @ 20
```

This lets you export a function using a different name, or export by ordinal only. Add it as a source file as follows:

```
cl testdll.c testdll.def /LD
```

Then in Python, for example:

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = cdll.testdll
>>> lib.sum_alias(1, 2)
3
>>> lib[10](1, 2)      
3
>>> lib[20](1, 2)
3
```

---

BTW, ctypes doesn't preload the exports from a DLL. `dir(lib)` won't show any function pointers at first. They're cached when accessed:

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = cdll.testdll
>>> sorted(vars(lib))
['_FuncPtr', '_handle', '_name']
>>> lib.sum_alias(1, 2)
3
>>> sorted(vars(lib))
['_FuncPtr', '_handle', '_name', 'sum_alias']
```