# Trying to compile simple dll written in C using gcc fails

Tags: c, gcc, dll, declspec

Trying to compile a simple DLL written in C using gcc.

Tried following many tutorials, but can't get it to compile even when I strip the file down to the very basics.

test_dll.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall hello() {
    printf ("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Trying to compile this using the command

```
gcc -c test_dll.c
```

Failing, getting this output

```
test_dll.c: In function '__declspec':
test_dll.c:3:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'hello'
 __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall hello() {
                                     ^
test_dll.c:5:1: error: expected '{' at end of input
 }
 ^
```

gcc version

```
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

Comment: are you compiling for windows? `__declspec(dllexport)` has to do with the special linker semantics in windows (import libraries) and is non-existent on other systems.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721364/creating-a-dll-in-gcc-or-cygwin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a DLL in GCC or Cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721364/creating-a-dll-in-gcc-or-cygwin)

Comment: I think you need to answer this question:   Is your target output for Windows or Linux?   Windows uses DLLs, whereas Linux (generally) uses SOs.  You seem to be using Linux (Ubuntu), so are you really trying to target a different operating system (Windows), or are you trying to create a SO to use on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I was indeed compiling for Windows. Didn't realize I needed to cross compile. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do:

#### 1. build a library for linux on linux

then remove the `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__stdcall`. On linux, you need nothing special in the source code for building a library. Note that libraries aren't DLLs on linux, they're named `*.so` (shared object). You'll have to compile with `-fPIC` and link with `-shared` to create your `.so` file. Please use google for more details on this.

#### 2. build a windows DLL on linux

Install mingw packages (search for them in your package manager). Then, instead of just `gcc`, invoke the cross compiler targeting windows/mingw, e.g. `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

#### 3. allow to build libraries cross-platform, including windows

If you want to be able to build a library from the same code on windows and linux, you'll need some preprocessor magic for this, so `__declespec()` is only used when targeting windows. I normally use something like this:

```
#undef my___cdecl
#undef SOEXPORT
#undef SOLOCAL
#undef DECLEXPORT

#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define my___cdecl extern "C"
#else
#  define my___cdecl
#endif

#ifndef __GNUC__
#  define __attribute__(x)
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#  define SOEXPORT my___cdecl __declspec(dllexport)
#  define SOLOCAL
#else
#  define DECLEXPORT my___cdecl
#  if __GNUC__ >= 4
#    define SOEXPORT my___cdecl __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#    define SOLOCAL __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#  else
#    define SOEXPORT my___cdecl
#    define SOLOCAL
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#  undef DECLEXPORT
#  ifdef BUILDING_MYLIB
#    define DECLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    ifdef MYLIB_STATIC
#      define DECLEXPORT my___cdecl
#    else
#      define DECLEXPORT my___cdecl __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

Then put a `DECLEXPORT` in front of each declaration to be exported by the lib and `SOEXPORT` in front of each definition. That's just a quick example.

Comment: You seem to have missed the alternative that he is writing a DLL for Windows on Windows and using gcc with e.g. Cygwin. The answer for Cygwin btw is the same as your section 1 but without `-fPic` needed.

Comment: @JeremyP nope, the question clearly states `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)`

Comment: OK didn't see that.

Comment: maybe it's the new windows 10 ubuntu subsystem ;)

Comment: I did hear that Microsoft are trialling a new kernel for Windows 11 that uses a core Linux kernel and a compatibility layer for the NT syscalls.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you! Worked for me. I did not realize that I had to use mingw for that as all examples I looked up used __declspec and compiled with standard gcc. The extended dll example is also very helpful.

Comment: @Casperscacion YW. To clarify, it's the usual convention that the compiler without a "host triplet" prefixed builds code for the same system it runs on, so if you're on linux, by invoking `gcc`, you build linux binaries, and on windows windows binaries. If you want to build windows binaries on linux, you need the prefixed version (cross compiler).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are compiling on Linux, the `gcc` takes Linux as the target.

What you want to do is cross compile for Windows. Which means you will need a cross compiler. The one available for Ubuntu Linux is mingw.

You can install it using

```
apt-get install gcc-mingw32
```

If the above command doesn't work then try the following

```
   apt-get install mingw-w64
```

Then you can compile with

```
gcc-mingw32 -c test_dll.c
```

Further compiling into dll would need

```
gcc-mingw32 --shared test_dll.o -o test_dll.dll
```

This dll can then be used on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but Felix answered first so I marked his answer.

Comment: It is more detailed anyway and explores all probables. So yeah, I don't mind.

Comment: Still a good answer for the cross-compiling case, so upvoting here -- and I'm a little surprised, Ubuntu really calls the mingw variant of gcc `gcc-mingw32`? This doesn't meet the convention (`[target-triplet]-gcc`) :o